# How to understand the results of nonlinear mixed-effects regression model

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-regression, fitting

I have some data, obtained from 4 different groups. Each repeat is some 4 parametric sigmoid. I need to fit the data to sigmoidal function and answer the question, whether sigmoids are different between groups. I wrote the following code (MatLab):

```
%% simulate data
% define parameters for each group
P = [[0 2500 -10 -0.2]; % grou1
    [-10 2000 -20 0];   % group2
    [100 1500 -1 0.1];  % group3
    [10 600 -5 -0.3]];  % group4
% simulate data
fnSigma = @(p,x) p(1) + (p(2)-p(1))./(1+exp(-p(3).*(x-p(4))));
grp = [];
Curves = [];
x = linspace(-1,1,20);
for iRep = 1:10
    for iGroup = 1:4
        Curves = [Curves;(fnSigma(P(iGroup,:),x)+normrnd(0,10,1,20))];
        grp = [grp;iGroup];
    end
end
% fit a nonlinear mixed-effects regression model
X = repmat(x,40,1);
G = repmat(grp,1,20);
P0 = mean(P);
[beta1,PSI1,stats1] = nlmefit(X(:),Curves(:),G(:),[],fnSigma,P0);
```

the problem is I do not understand the output:

```
beta1 =

   1.0e+03 *

   -0.0000
    1.6600
   -0.0089
   -0.0001

PSI1 =

   1.0e+05 *

    0.0006         0         0         0
         0    4.9275         0         0
         0         0    0.0005         0
         0         0         0    0.0000

stats1 = 

 struct with fields:

       dfe: 791
      logl: -3.0316e+03
       mse: 95.6008
      rmse: 9.7410
errorparam: 9.7776
       aic: 6.0813e+03
       bic: 6.0758e+03
      covb: [4×4 double]
    sebeta: [4.5810 351.0160 3.5396 0.0948]
      ires: [800×1 double]
      pres: [800×1 double]
     iwres: [800×1 double]
     pwres: [800×1 double]
     cwres: [800×1 double]
```

**Could you educate me and explain what does this output means?**

Comment: Where is your output?